# Download data when web view button on remote web site is clicked objective c

Tags: web, webview, xcode8

When using Safari and click a button I can download a file to the Download folder.
I need to do the same using web view in mac os x nothing is downloaded.

What can I do to download to Download folder in web view in mac os x?